# Make controller return a part dynamically to any page that has the widget when !ModelState.IsValid

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, orchardcms

So I've made an orchard module that is basically a contact form as a widget. This widget can be placed on any page as a part(or as a widget) and it posts it's data to a controller that handles the post data, once it sends the email it returns a "sent" view which summarizes their input. The issue I'm having is handling an invalid model. As I debug the code, it steps into the validation just fine.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   //Gets here no problem
}
```

But the problem is that since my widget can basically be on any page (home page, on a separate page, in a global area so its on every page), it can be a widget or part of a type. I don't know how to send the model back to the sender page. I'm thinking I have a few options.

An interesting side note is that if I put my form in a "global" area of my site( as in a side bar that's on every page, more importantly my "sent" page) then the form on that page will actually have the "validation" errors render on the form. So somehow it's still passing my view-model to a page even thought I don't explicitly return it.

a) Somehow map the sender url to a controller action, for example if the url has no subdomain, then we route it to a homepage controller or whatever (not sure how orchard handles it)

b) Somehow do it in the handler/driver area, also not sure how I'd do this.

c) Rather not do it this way but just make my controller return json data and make the form post to the controller async via jquery.

Answer (score -1):

I would personally go the JSON/Ajax way if you have no hard-requirement that the system MUST work when Javascript is not enabled (or when you can accept that your system is handicapped when Javascript is disabled). Plus it gives your side a nice behavior... what AJAX does to any site ;).

Either render your contact widget as a PartialView or PartialAction (either should work, you probably already have this running.

```
@* This is, of course, oversimplified for the sake keeping the post short. 
   I'd be happy to provide more details if you need'em *@
<form id="contact" action="@Url.Action("ContactWidget", "Send")" method="post">
{
    @Html.Textbox("name");
    @Html.TextArea("message");
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

Then use some Javascript (and jQuery in this example). Ideally in a separately included .js file (given this file will be all over the site, it'll reduce your pages size since .js are cacheable).

```
$('form#contact input[type=submit]').on('click', function () {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    var data = form.serialize();
    var postURL = form.attr('action');

    // do the actual post
    $.post(postURL, data, function (response) {
        if (response) {
            form.parent().html($(response));
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

That will replace the content's of the form's container with the response that you get out of your POST call. So, at this point, you can implement your Controller's Send action anyway you like and have it respond with a Partial View content. Whether that HTML it returns is the same form with validation errors, or a "Thank you" message, is up to you. 
It could be something like...

```
public ActionResult Send(SendViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View("Widget", model); // where "Widget" is the .cshtml with the form

    // do the actual message sending...

    // return a thank you note
    return View("ThankYou"); // where "ThankYou" is the .cshtml with the Thank You message
}
```

Note that even if Javascript is not enabled, your widget will do a full-browser POST to your Widget, but the result will only be the output of the contact form. I won't go into this unless you need me to, but you may be able to use the Request.IsAjaxRequest() extension and the HttpReferrer to redirect the user to the original page after processing the POST.